# Convert date from json to regular format in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got from json with date,  date format  is `"2011-03-13T11:30:00Z"` , and I want to convert it into normal format .

`var Date= "Sunday, March 13th, 2011 "` and `var Time = "11:30"`

i want to make it separate as above with proper format.
please help me....

Comment: `a = new Date('2011-03-13T11:30:00Z');` `var Time =a.getHours()+':'+a.getMinutes();`

Comment: hey I am not getting correct Time. why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new `Date` object with the date string from the json data and then use the objects methods to get the date formats you want

```
var dateObject = new Date("2011-03-13T11:30:00Z");

var time = dateObject.getHours() + ':' + dateObject.getMinutes();
```

You also have the following which you could use to construct your date

```
dateObject.getDay(); // would return 0 for Sunday (days run 0-6 starting at Sun)
dateObject.getMonth(); // would return 2 for March (months run 0-11)
dateObject.getFullYear(); // return 2011
```

As per comments, to correct this for timezones, you need to know that the `Z` in your string denotes `UTC/GMT`, so if you are not in that timezone you need to correct for your difference to UTC

For example, replace the `Z` with `+05:30` for being 5.5 hours ahead of UTC

```
var dateString = "2011-03-13T11:30:00Z".replace('Z', '+05:30');
var dateObject = new Date(dateString);
```

Comment: Hey.. Hi Thanks for snippet. Date, Month and Year getting correctly as your saying but time is not getting in correct format... is der any another way to fetch the time .

Comment: @addy are you using my original or updated answer. `getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since unix epoch, the update shows how to get the hours and minutes in a string as you requested

Comment: `var a = new Date("2011-03-13T11:30:00Z");
var Time =a.getHours()+':'+a.getMinutes();
alert("Time = "+Time);` Time= 17:0 This is my result which I am getting.

Comment: How odd.  I just copied the relevant code from your comment into this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9FPk/) and it works... alerts 11:30.  Try it yourself.  Do you have other code that may be affecting this?

Comment: hey i have checked with Firefox and Chrome still m getting the same alert. Why this?

Comment: What time zone are you in?  India Standard Time by any chance? Or possibly Rangoon/Burma?  Either 5.5 or 6.5 hours ahead of GMT

Comment: `(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi` This is my System Time Zone  `Yes you are right its ahead of 5.30 hrs`

Comment: Yes you are right its ahead of 5.30 hrs`. How Can i decrease my timing by 5.30 hrs.

Comment: sorry I am disturbing you again. i want the `13` value from  "2011-03-`13`T11:30:00Z". Please Help me.

Comment: Check out the docs [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate) for a list of all methods.  You would need the `getDate()` method